# How do I read a cookie created in jquery from code behind in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, cookies

I have created a cookie in javascript...

```
(document).ready(function () {
    $.cookie("test", "Hello Michael");
    alert($.cookie("test"));
});
```

The alert displays the cookie content as expected.
And I am trying to read it back in vb.net code behind...

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie
cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("test")

If IsNothing(cookie) Then
  txtCookie.Text = "Cookie not found"
Else
  txtCookie.Text = cookie.Value
End If
```

I always get 'Cookie not found".

I am clearly missing something... please advise!

Comment: `(document)`, `$` missing..a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `path` value to the cookie,

```
$.cookie("test", "Hello Michael", { path : "/" });
```

And, `Request.Cookies("test")` would work.
Also, `(document)`, `$` is missing.